# how to guide pm2 ignore folder

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

How to make pm2 to ignore a certain folder?

My npm script is like this

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production PORT=8080 node -r esm ./bin/www",
        "dev": "nodemon -r esm ./bin/www",
        "pm2": "pm2 start npm --name app -- start --watch",
    },
```

my pm2 ecosytem file is like this

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            ignore_watch: ['sql'],
            watch_options: {
                followSymlinks: false,
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

When I start server with pm2 I use this command

```
npm run pm2
```

I want pm2 to ignore the folder sql, So far it doesn't work, what am I missing ?

Comment: is there sql folder in the root of project? path of sql folder is correct?

Comment: sql is in the root. the same place as package.js. I checked, it's correct